# Windows 10 update assistant stuck at 99 percent when updating 1909 to 2004

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1909, windows-10-v2004

after releasing 2004 version of windows 10 i have waited a long time for it to roll out for my device but it did not yet, i checked for update with windows 10 update assistant and it showed me that i can update to 2004 but during the updating progress it got stuck at 99 percent, i waited for hours it didn't work then i tried some cmd command that i found about windows update services, stop/start the windows update from services.msc,disconnecting the internet,disabling the windows defender and then restarting the system and retrying the update now it have been +12 hours and it stuck at 99 percent again i have limited data and i don't want to re download all of the update again what is the solution that i may do to finish the update without having to restart?

Answer (score 2):

[According to Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027554/windows-windows-10-upgrade-assistant-is-stuck-at-99) this is what you should do:

1.Open File Explorer, type C:\$GetCurrent, and then press Enter.

2.Copy and paste the Media folder to the desktop. If you don't see the folder, select View and make sure the check box next to Hidden items is selected.

3.Restart your PC, open File Explorer, type C:\$GetCurrent in the address bar, and then press Enter.

4.Copy and paste the Media folder from the desktop to C:\$GetCurrent.
Open the Media folder and double-click Setup.

5.Follow the instructions to start the upgrade. **On the Get important updates screen, select Not right now, and then select Next.** *This option may be hidden behind "Change how Windows Setup downloads updates"*

6.Follow the instructions to finish upgrading to Windows 10. After you're done, make sure to install available updates. Select the Start  button, and then select Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Update > Check for updates.

Comment: Thanks i tried this solution update stuck at 31% first time i restarted the device and the second time it updated