# Windows 10 update won't fetch new updates despite being on 1909

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Windows update is not updating on several systems. They're all on 1909 and I left them to think for hours but no luck.

[I was hoping I could find and use the C:$GetCurrent](https://superuser.com/questions/1569857/windows-10-update-assistant-stuck-at-99-percent-when-updating-1909-to-2004) directory but it does not exist (cant visit as admin)

They're either saying they are up to date or that they're not and are missing updates:

[image]

Internet is wide open for these systems.

Comment: Run the Windows Update Troubleshooter (all sections ) and see if that works.   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-update-troubleshooter-19bc41ca-ad72-ae67-af3c-89ce169755dd

Comment: I would also try cleaning the Component Store: Close Windows Update → `WinKey`+`R` → _Open:_ `powershell` → `Shift`+`Ctrl`+OK → `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` → Once it finishes, re-open Windows Update and search for updates.

Comment: Try going into Windows Update, go to Advanced Options, enable Updating for other Microsoft Products, and allow Downloading of content through measured connections. Afterward, manually force the update. 

If that doesn't work, go to space cleanup, select clean system files (you'll need admin access), and select Windows Update Cleanup. Once cleanup is finished, retry the previous steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can to enter these machines as user, simply download the updater from microsoft site.
https://www.microsoft.com/pl-pl/software-download/windows10

get the update now.

It worked for me few times like that.

Comment: You don’t download Feature Updates from the Windows Update Catalog. This answer seems more like a comment since it doesn’t attempt to explain how to identify which updates are missing.  Since the author is using an unsupported version of Windows 10, they will find that, Windows Update Catalog will only have updates for 1909 that the author will be unable to install.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the original question. Author wanted to do feature update for older systems. My answer is a great workaround when the feature update is not showing on windows update center. And as you can see, its marked as the answer.